# Did I mess up my lab experiment ? (active low pass filter)

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, active-filter

This is the table of the readings and I have worked out the gain which is $$\frac{Vout}{Vin}$$ and I got all 5 at the beginning ... but I also remember that the values of the resistors in the feedback loop determine the gain, which supposed to be 10, does that mean I totally messed up everything ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering SE. Looking at the data all looks good. [Low pass filter graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#/media/File:Butterworth_response.svg)

Comment: hello, but there is something that i don't understand .. the values of the resistors give me a gain of 10 , so why would the highest value of the gain here is 5 ?

Comment: Can your draw the circuit with the resistor values? Try using this link http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask or you can access the link from the editor, the 7th button  where you have the bold options etc

Comment: sorry i couldn't find the place so i used a website to do it

Comment: What is V+ of your opamp power supply?

Comment: can't really remember , but what I'm saying is if the values of the resistors 2*10^3+18*10^3 / 2*10^3 = 10 which is the gain of t, what should the vin/vout become in the table ?

Comment: does that mean there is a conflict between the gain = vout/vin from the experiment and the theory of the resistors ?

Comment: Yes there is, there are several potential issues here: 1) You would like a gain of 10 yet you use 2 V input voltage, so if the gain was 10 you would get 20 V output voltage. Your supply would need to be +15 V and -15 V. Is it ? 2) You couple Vin directly, that is OK but make sure there is no DC offset on Vin. If there would be then the output could clip against one of the supplies. Remember that the DC offset at Vin will also be amplified 10x 3) For the values of R2 and R3 as shown your gain will be 18k/(18k + 2 k) so a little bit more than 1, i.e. not 10. Exchange R2 and R3 to make it 10x

Comment: You can't get 20V output with a +/- 15V supply

Comment: You can depending on how you define the 20 V, if it's 20 Vpeak-peak you can (+10V to -10V). But 20 V peak you cannot as that would be 40 Vpp (+20V to -20 V which is more than +/- 15 V).

Comment: 10V looks suspiciously like limiting at the rail supply voltage.